# Inserting an image into sqlserver gives an "operand type clash"

Tags: php, sql-server, image

I'm trying to save an image in a sql server 2000 database.
The data type of the column is `image`.

I get the following error:

> Error: Warning: odbc_exec()
>   [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash:
>   text is incompatible with image, SQL
>   state 22005 in SQLExecDirect in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\upload.php on
>   line 25 Error, query failed

Here is the code:

#### Image Upload:

```
<?php

    include('config.php');

    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))
    {
        $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

        $size = filesize($tmpName);
        set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);//to desactive the default escape spacials caracters made by PHP in the externes files

        $img_binaire = base64_encode(fread(fopen(str_replace("'","''",$tmpName), "r"), $size));

        $query = "INSERT INTO test_image (image_name, image_content, image_size) ".
        "VALUES ('{$fileName}','{$img_binaire}', '{$size}')";

        odbc_exec($conn, $query) or die('Error, query failed'); 

        echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
        echo "<br>File Size: $fileSize <br>";
    } 
?>
```

#### Image Show:

```
<?php
    include('config.php');

    $sql = "select * from test_image where id =2";
    $rsl = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
    $image_info = odbc_fetch_array($rsl);
    //$count = sizeof($image_info['image_content']);


    //header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    //header('Content-Length: '.$image_info['image_size']);
    //header("Content-length: 17397");
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 
    echo base64_decode($image_info['image_content']);

    //echo bindec($image_info['image_content']);
?>
```

What do I need to do differently?

Comment: Where do you have your error? At insert or at display time?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least one error here: `base64_encode(fread(fopen(str_replace("'","''",$tmpName), "r"), $size));`
str_replace must be removed as it would spoil your data.

There can be other errors too. you have to debug your code.

Comment: No still there is same error. Please watch the warning message